# Automatically importing and merging bands in each folder from QGIS

Tags: qgis, merge, band

How do I automatically import and merge the bands in each folder from QGIS?

The `C:\landsat` path contains the Landsat 5 image folder.

[image]

Inside each folder is a Landsat image.

[image]

I want to automatically merge B3 (red), B2 (green), and B3 (blue) of each image into RGB (True Color).

How do I automatically take a band (R,G,B) of each folder from QGIS using commands, Python Console, etc. and merge it into RGB?

Comment: You say B3 twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use python to list the files/bands, sort the band list 3-2-1, and merge. You will likely need to modify this somewhere so try it on a folder with one date in it first:

```py
import os, re
#os to search for folders and files and manipulate paths, re to extract a date from a filename


infolder = r'E:\Data\Satellit\test' #Your landsat folder, change this line
outfolder = r'E:\Data\Satellit\output_test' #Where the merge outputs will be saved, and this line
bands = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'] #substrings to search for in each bands filename 
fileFormat = '.tif'

#Find the folders inside infolder, just the first level subfolders (=the different dates)
subfolders = [os.path.join(infolder, i) for i in os.listdir(infolder) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(infolder, i))]

for subfolder in subfolders: #For each of them
    print(f'Processing folder {subfolder}')
    bandlist = [] #A list to hold the band filenames
    for root, folder, files in os.walk(subfolder):
        for file in files: #For each file in the subfolder
            #Find the files with b1, b2 or b3 in the name and with tif extension
            if any([b in file.lower() for b in bands]) and file.lower().endswith(fileFormat):
                bandlist.append(os.path.join(root, file)) #Append full name to the list
    bandlist.sort(reverse=True) #Sort the list by filename B03-B02-B01
    thedate = re.search(r'\d{8}', os.path.basename(bandlist[0])).group(0) #Extract a 8 digit number, the date, from one of the files
    outfile = os.path.join(outfolder, f"image_{thedate}.tif") #Use it to name the output image_20210713.tif
    #Merge using the bandlist and output filename
    processing.run("gdal:merge", {'INPUT':bandlist,'PCT':False,
        'SEPARATE':True,'NODATA_INPUT':None,'NODATA_OUTPUT':None,
        'OPTIONS':'','EXTRA':'','DATA_TYPE':5,'OUTPUT':outfile})
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped me a lot. Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

Use `Menu Raster > Miscellaneous > Merge` (see [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rastermiscellaneous.html#merge)) and run it in batch mode to convert several rasters at once. Check the box next to `Place each input file into a separate band`.